# how to connect three dataloaders together in pytorch - parallel not chained

Tags: python, pytorch, generator, yield, pytorch-dataloader

i have three same length dataloaders (A,B,C) that load images (a,b,c), i want to create a new dataloader D that loads a dict of images, some syntax for clarity:

usually the dataloader works like this:

```
for a in A:
    a -> an image
```

i want to have the following:

```
for d in D:
    d -> dict such that {'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}
```

i managed to get my desired result by doing so:

```
def chain_multi_transforms_loader(loader_list):
    for x_1,x_2,x_3 in zip(loader_list[0],loader_list[1],loader_list[2]):
        X = {'1':x_1,'2':x_2,'3':x_3}
        yield X
if __name__ == '__main__':
    D = chain_multi_transforms_loader([A,B,C])
    for d in D:
        d-> {'1':x_1,'2':x_2,'3':x_3}
```

this is exactly what i want, but the problem is that it has one time use. i want to use it epoch after epoch. even better if it contains all the logic of pytorch shuffling so that i will not need to force the same seed on all three loaders that compose the overall loader.

any ideas how to go about it?

Comment: why do you want to merge `DataLoader`s and not the underlying `Dataset`s?

Comment: i have one dataset, but i have three different transforms for it, and i want to pass a dict containing the same image but transformed in three different ways.
the pytorch dataloader func accepts a transforms object, so i wanted to create three dataloaders that are identical except for the transforms object, that was my direction

Comment: it's the `Dataset` that gets the `transform` argument, isn't it? https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html

Comment: Make sure you are not confusing `Dataset` with `DataLoader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the underlying `Dataset`s:

```py
class ParallelDictDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, base_dataset, *transforms):
    super(ParallelDictDataset, self).__init__()
    self.dataset = base_dataset
    self.transforms = transforms

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    img, label = self.dataset[idx]
    item = {f'{i}': t(img) for i, t in enumerate(self.transforms)}
    return item

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.dataset)
```

This new `Dataset` gets a *single* [`ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html) dataset *without* any transformations, and a list of transformations each defining a different element in the new dataset.

Now you can define a **single** `DataLoader` that gets a `ParallelDictDataset` and each batch returned from this `Dataloader` will be a dict.